# Passing parameter through constructor vs public methods

Tags: c++, function, oop, constructor

I am hearing conflicted arguments from my friends about parameter passing,  when to pass input through constructor and when through the public methods?

First scenario, all arguments for public methods initialized in constructor. Argument for this: If the amount of parameters for the functions is a lot larger than the toy example, it will look a lot cleaner. Argument against this: in some use cases I only need to call func1 which is dependent only on a1, needing to initialize a2 create unnecessary coupling. Not immediately clear on what input each function is depending on.

```
class A
{
 public:
  A(int a1, int a2) : m_a1(a1), m_a2(a2) {};
  func1(){ //do something with m_a1 };
  func2(){ //do something with m_a1, m_a2 };
 private:
  int m_a1;
  int m_a2;
};
```

Second scenario, nothing is initialized in constructor. Argument for this: Immediately clear on what inputs the functions are depending on, and there are no unnecessary coupling. Argument against this: This becomes just a collection of functions, why use classes at the first place? Code will be cluttered with repetitive similar parameters if there are more functions and parameters in the code.

```
class A
{
 public:
  func1(int a1){ //do something with a1 };
  func2(int a1, int a2){ //do something with a1, a2 };
};
```

Third scenario, only common arguments for public methods initialized in constructor. Seems to be getting the best of both sides but it also has the disadvantage from both sides.

```
class A
{
 public:
  A(int a1) : m_a1(a1) {};
  func1(){ //do something with m_a1 };
  func2(int m_a2){ //do something with m_a1, a2 };
 private:
  int m_a1;
};
```

Additional question is if the class is restricted to only have one single public method, is the first scenario or the second scenario considered as better practice?

Comment: If it would be valid for your parameter to be a private member, I can't see how making it a function parameter wouldn't break the program.

Comment: It sounds to me like `A` has no business being a class in the first place, what does `A` do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your judgements hold true IMO. Make it a member variable if it is an integral part of the object represented by the class. Suppose you are making a class `Car`. Then `engine`, `gearbox`, `brake` etc. will be all member variables, even though you'll use `engine` and `gearbox` in `SpeedUp()`, and `brake` in `SlowDown()`.

So in your case, if `a1` and `a2` really belong to `A`, it is definitely a good choice to declare them as member variables rather than passing to the functions explicitly.

Hope you got my point.